# Rosdep Init cannot download default sources

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just upgraded to 18.04 which required uninstalling ROS from 16.04 (or was I the only one with this issue?).  Installing ROS Melodic and I cannot get "sudo rosdep init" to run:

```
~$ sudo rosdep init
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.
```

I see that something about the Github URLs was updated in 0.15.1 ROSDEP (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst) and I'm wondering if there's some issue that is not my own?  I've tried removing rosdep and reinstalling with no success.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316260/rosdep-init-cannot-download-default-sources/) by [jtroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/40126/jtroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-02-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jtroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/40126/jtroll/) on 2019-02-22**:
With a browser I am able to get to each of the URLS listed in: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list

**Comment by [jtroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/40126/jtroll/) on 2019-02-22**:
This file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml) states:

gbp-repos:
? You must update to a newer rosdep version by calling..sudo apt-get update && sudo
apt-get install python-rosdep (make sure to uninstall the pip version on Ubuntu)

Is that my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally got past this, thank goodness.  After lots of reading and hacking and try-try-trying again, there are a two things I did to correct this that I want to point out for the community:

1. I manually installed the "DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server" certificate with instructions from this site:
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates/+bug/1795242

This seems necesarry to talk to raw.github.com.  That did not fix everything by itself, but seemed to be necessary based on connectivity issues I was having.  Not sure why this wasn't already installed, but I don't know anything about certificates.  I don't know if this was the issue.

What then ultimately fixed it for me was this:

2. Editing c_rehash lines 15 and 16 to point to "/usr/local/ssl" and copying certificates to that location, which has something to do with making "wget work as before upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04".  I found those instructions at this site: https://superuser.com/questions/1387295/ca-certificates-is-broken-or-not-fully-installed

---

Originally posted by [jtroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/40126/jtroll/) with karma: 26 on 2019-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noone](https://answers.ros.org/users/44006/noone/) on 2019-07-06**:
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and it still doesn't work , it still cannot connect to raw.github.com
And I don't have the problem that stated in superuser site.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a lot of similar questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=rosdep+init+cannot+download+site:answers.ros.org

This is most commonly an issue with network connectivity.

You're having issues with the new url so it's not related to the recent update to rosdep for the github url change.

You should validate that you can get to that url by default.

As for the upgrade yes, you cannot keep the same ROS version installed between 16.04 and 18.04 as they are not both supported by a single ROS distro. See here for target platforms: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is caused by network issues
You can try to setup this with proxy
https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng

when you have setup proxychains,

then
sudo proxychains4  rosdep init

sudo proxychains4   rosdep update

---

Originally posted by [KOOYOO](https://answers.ros.org/users/38057/kooyoo/) with karma: 61 on 2019-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IcameIgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/54109/icameigo/) on 2020-04-28**:
this is the simplist way I tried. thanks.